# How to stop Jenkins from redirect to port 8443?

Tags: jenkins

We have SSL certificate on port 8080, and we bind public port 8080 to local port 8080. However, when login Jenkins, it redirects to port 8443, got a "can't reach this page".

How can I stop this redirect?

Update:

1. I checked with Chrome plugin "link redirect trace", found that the following change in the url:

> ```
> https://ourdomain.com:8080
>
> https://ourdomain.com:8080/login?from=%2F
>
> https://ourdomain.com:8080/j_spring_security_check
>
> https://ourdomain.com:8443
> ```

2. Although the login redirect to 8443 (can't reach this page). When I open port 8080, the account has been logged in.

Update 2:

I am puzzled about where the port number 8443 comes from, so I searched Jenkins's source code:

In `jenkins/core/src/test/java/jenkins/model/JenkinsGetRootUrlTest.java`

in function `useForwardedProtoWithIPv6WhenPresent`  of line 162 - 165

```
    accessing("http://[::1]:8080/jenkins/");
    withHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto", "https");
    withHeader("X-Forwarded-Host", "[::1]:8443");
    rootUrlFromRequestIs("https://[::1]:8443/jenkins/");
```

It seems Jenkins thought that we are using IPv6. I tried to turn off
`X-Forwarded-Proto` header in the load balancer, now the login would redirect to the right port 8080. However, In Jenkins config page, it prompt `It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.`

I don't know whether it is critical. Why Jenkins consider we are using IPv6?

Comment: On the `/configure` page what is the `Jenkins URL` under Jenkins Location set to?

Comment: @apr_1985 Jenkins URL: https://ourdomain.com:8080/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because Jenkins by default runs HTTP on port 8080 and HTTPS on port 8443.  So on login Jenkins is seeing the request as HTTPS as passing it through to its configured HTTPS port.
You would probably need to run Jenkins with the options

```
--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080
```

The -1 will disable http and then it should bind 8080 to HTTPS.

(note I dont have a test bed to try this on but from the docs should be alright https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/)

Comment: Thanks. I set `JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT="8080"` in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`. It still redirect to 8443. Weird is: after this when I revisit 8080, the accout has been logged in.

Comment: is there any solution for this?